# brakes cause electrical power loss in cabin?

Tags: electrical, brakes, chevrolet, silverado

In my 06 Silverado, when I press the brake pedal while the truck is parked and turned off, the radio will turn on. If I adjust the dial for the dash lights brightness, the dash cluster will power on is if the the key is in the ignition and running. While I'm driving and I press the brakes, my dash lights, dome light, air bag indicator light on my rearview mirror, and cigarette lighter ports lose power/turn off. Also the AC fan motor and wipers do not work unless I hit a pretty extreme bump in the road. If I turn the AC fan on full blast or the wipers to full speed when they are not working, my dash lights, dome light, air bag indicator light on my rearview mirror, and cigarette lighter ports lose power/turn off as well. In other words, I need help...

Comment: Had the same issue with a Chrysler product years ago..a wiring loop Never solved it. After 4 decades I figured the Americans would have solved it. A schematic might have helped...Sorry

Comment: Did you install any aftermarket components? Radio? Lights?

Comment: Have you had the battery tested? Have you traced the entire wire harness (especially grounds) inspecting for damage? Also, Inspect for water damage around/behind the fuse box(es).

Comment: Test your ground(s) when the brake pedal is down.

Answer (score 1):

The symptoms you describe suggest some possible faults and, likely, a combination:

Faulty brake light bulbs (which connect brake wire to sidelight wire - had this in the past)

Crossed or joined wires that are « back-feeding » the circuits.

Poor / loose connections for ground / earth for the dash...

Poor / loose ground for the rear lights...

However, finding the issue(s) is a time-consuming process so good luck...